# Error when trying to use `assert not mock.method.called`

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm trying to assert that a method is not called using Python Mock. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get past this error:

```
AttributeError: MockCallable instance has no attribute 'called'
```

I'm running Python 2.7.1 and Python Mock 0.1.0 for my tests. Google says: `No results found for "AttributeError: MockCallable instance has no attribute 'called'".` How can I resolve this error?

Here's the test:

```
import unittest2
import main
from mock import Mock

class TestCli(unittest2.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mockView = Mock()
        self.mockFriendManager = Mock()
        self.mockedCli = main.CLI(self.mockView, self.mockFriendManager)

[...]

    def testCliDoesntGetFriendPropertiesWhenNotSelected(self):
        view = Mock( { "requestResponse":2 } )
        friendManager = Mock()
        cli = main.CLI(view, friendManager)
        cli.outputMenu()
        assert not friendManager.getFriendProperties.called, 'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

You must update you `mock` library by `pip`. Attribute `called` was introduced in 0.4.0 as you can see in http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/changelog.html#version-0-4-0

Anyway by update it you will get a lot of more useful facilities and tools.